# Comparing a list of 1 column tibbles to a single 1 column tibble

Tags: r

I am very new to programming when it comes to R and I think I am in over my head with what I am trying to do. I have a list of 9 tibbles each made of 1 column that contain ~50 items as characters. I would like to compare each tibble in the list to another 1 column tibble. I already know none of the tibbles are identical but some of the values are. Thus I would like to each comparison to return a list of TRUE or FALSE values depending on whether or not each value from the list of tibbles is found in the single tibble. Comparing 2 tibbles individually is easy as I used %in% but the hard part is iterating through the list of tibbles to make the comparisons without having to do comparisons 1 at a time using the %in% command.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
mapply(function(x,y){any(x %in% y)}, tibble_list, single_tibble)
```

This only compares the tibbles and returns FALSE for everything because they are not equal.

```
for (val in tibble_list) {val$Column.Name %in% single_tibble$Column.Name}
```

This prints everything perfectly but when I try to store the values it only stores the last iteration.

I suspect a map function could be used but like I said I am new to R and this is very different from Python.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a single column in the `tibble_list`, to be compared  with the 'single_tibble'  column,  we  can use `lapply` or `map` (from `purrr`)

```
 out <- lapply(tibble_list, function(dat) dat$Column.Name %in% single_tibble$Column.Name)
```

---

In the `for` loop, we need to assign to a `list` the output from each iteration

```
out1 <- vector('list', length(tibble_list))
for (i in seq_along(tibble_list)) {
        out1[[i]] <- tibble_list[[i]]$Column.Name %in% single_tibble$Column.Name
   }
```